# can you create tempfile without writing to the hard drive

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, ram, temporary-files

I am trying to write a main program we'll call it program (A) that can create a tempfile WITHOUT writing it to hhd/sdcard, hopefully in the ram. I would like program (B) to be able to read this file.

In my main program(A) i'm using a threaded loop to read the tmpfile for changes. In a completely different program (B) it has a gui with a assigned variable that can change program (A) tempfile contents and the following changes will be updated from programs (A) loop reader

I have seen the "tempfile" module but from what i can see it does write to the hdd. I am trying to keep from the wear and tear of reading an writing
files to my hdd/sdcard any help would be much appreciated. I used socket module for somethings on my RPI but i can't get mind around some of it.

On a side note my programs are all based in python 2.7 at the moment i'm trying to do this with a RPI(arm) but would love to also use this is in some of my linux mint 18 applications(x64) hopefully i made myself clear thanks to all.

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: filesize is less than 100kb, i must have misunderstood i thought the tempfile would post to the sdcard then when the program closed it would delete it assuming you had the delete option set to True

Comment: Use a RAMdisk, `mkdir /tmp/RAMdisk` then `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024k tmpfs /tmp/RAMdisk` Now your app can create files in `/tmp/RAMdisk`

Comment: Or use **Redis** which is an *in-memory data structure server* and is brilliant - having queues and hashes and sets...

Comment: This looks like a classical "if all you have is a hammer.."  problem. This seems like a classic client/server program so you can use all the usual things here. Simply hosting a web server on localhost for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using a RAMdisk, which is backed by RAM rather than your SD card:

```
# Create a mount point
mkdir -p /tmp/RAMdisk

# Create and mount a RAMdisk of 1 megabyte
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024k tmpfs /tmp/RAMdisk
```

Now your app can create files in `/tmp/RAMdisk` without writing to your SD card.

Note that the contents will be lost on reboot.

Answer (score -1):

You can use named pipes if you work on linux: [here](https://gist.github.com/zed/7378451)

Comment: A named pipe has different semantics from a regular file, and wouldn't be compatible with the OP's use case (where B writes changes back to the file that A will read).

Comment: Named pipes are also not specific to Linux.

Comment: so to be clear with pipes, could program (A) have a variable pass to a program(B)?